# ajax data doesn't fall into success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax and trying to fill a table with the data coming from a server.

Here is my GET function:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "myURL",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(response, function (i, v) {
                    // append to table
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + v.Ticker+
                              '</td><td>' + v.Close+
                              '</td><td>' + v.percentage+
                              '</td></tr>';
                });
                $("#art").append(trHTML);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                debugger;
                console.log(e)
                alert(e + " Error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Incoming data falls into **Error** every single time and it is like:

```
e = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"Ticker":"akbnk.is","Close":6.74,"percentage":-1…s","Close":1.54,"percentage":9.2198581560283781}]", s
```

I can see this much on Chrome. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: As i can see your response not seems like Valid json. So remove `dataType: "jsonp"`

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Can you write this as an answer?

Comment: @kalahari jsonp is needed when your ajax call is communicating with a different domain. If this isn't the case you can replace jsonp without any risk.

Comment: JSONP was superseded by CORS years ago. There's no good reason to do new development using JSONP in 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response not [`JSONP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) so when you trying to use ajax request with `dataType: "jsonp",` response must be of same `JSONP`. If it will not then it doesn't come in success callback.

So either remove `dataType: "jsonp"` or change `dataType: "json"` or change your response to `JSONP`.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> dataType: "jsonp",
> ```

Your data says:

> ```
> {"Ticker":"akbnk.is","C
> ```

Your data appears to be JSON. JSON is not JSONP, so it errors.

Either say `"json"` or change the server to return [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about).